# Adding image to Tableview

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am using SDWebImage to populate my Tableview with Images (downloaded and displayed).

What i did was i included the library in my project, then added the nessasry frameworks as mentioned in its GitHub project website.

Then i added `#import "UIImageView+WebCache.h"` the import, and the delegate `SDWebImageManagerDelegate`

In the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, i added the following;

CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

```
 if (cell == nil) {
 cell = [[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

 [cell.animalImageView  setImageWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString:animal.imageURL]
                                        placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imagenotfound.png"]];

}
```

I presume this does everything as described in its project website

> An UIImageView category adding web image and cache management to the
>   Cocoa Touch framework An asynchronous image downloader An asynchronous
>   memory + disk image caching with automatic cache expiration handling A
>   guarantee that the same URL won't be downloaded several times A
>   guarantee that bogus URLs won't be retried again and again
>   Performances!

But, when i run the application in on my phone, the scrolling is slow. then when i scroll up and down for awhile, it almost gets stuck (but it still scrolls).

Can someone please go through my code, and tell me what i have missed. I have been stuck with this issue for days. Help

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are my thoughts:
Are you using the [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
 method or are you creating a new cell for each row? 
The cell isn't autoreleased. 
How big are the images and the default image?

Comment: Yes, i am using `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier` . (i have edited my code above). I am using ARC, so need not autorelease. Images are less than 100KB, the default image is 40kb.

Comment: Try sharing your code for the CustomCell. Are you creating lots of views for example? Are you doing anything in DrawRect or layoutSubviews methods for example?

Answer (score 1):

You should put assigning image statement outside of that checking nil condition as

```
if (cell == nil) 
{
 cell = [[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

[cell.animalImageView  setImageWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString:animal.imageURL]
                                        placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imagenotfound.png"]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can try to declare an NSMutableArray and store the UIImage there, so you don't have to download them twice when you scroll

Comment: How can i do this programatically ? can you kindly demonstrate ?

Comment: SDWebImage uses a cache so it won't get downloaded twice.